# How to animate the icon in xamarin forms tabbed page

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

It shows the images but doesn't play the animation.

That's my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QRCodeScanner"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             x:Class="QRCodeScanner.MainPage"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
             BarBackgroundColor="Black"
             SelectedTabColor="Beige"
             UnselectedTabColor="DimGray">

    <ContentPage IconImageSource="generator.gif"/>
    <ContentPage IconImageSource="scanner.gif"/>
    
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: I think you can use the `<Image Source="generator.gif" IsAnimationPlaying="True"/>` tag.

Comment: @PaulSinnema but then it is not displayed in the icon

Comment: Per ms docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page .In iOS and Andorid,each tab consists of a title and an icon, which should be a `PNG` file with an alpha channel So I think it's not possible to make the icon as a gif.